# Cannot connect to Google Play from App Center to distribute App

Tags: google-api, google-play-console, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

When I click on Settings > Developer Account > API Access or Linked Acccounts. I get the error You need Permission.

[Linking your API Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/stores/googleplay#linking-your-api-project)

I have admin rights to my Play Console, and I am the owner of my Service Account which I want to access

How can I link my app in Play Console to App Center, so I can distribute from App Center to Play store?

Comment: I'm facing same problem, have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: @Philip, Your comment reminded me of this question.. I've since found the solution, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem.

It turns out that only the original developer account is able to do this.

- Even if the related GCP project is moved to be a child of an organization you administrate.
- Even if your account has "owner" access rights in the play console.

You *have* to be the original account owner. Don't ask me why.